# How can I make gcc preserve additional registers?

Tags: gcc, assembly

On `x86_64`, I would like to compile a `C` function with gcc that preserves all registers except `rax`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What is your specific use case for doing that?

Comment: I don't think gcc can do this out of the box, however it should be easily possible to add a custom calling convention for doing this.

Comment: Write a function in assembly that saves all the registers and then calls the C function, passing arguments as necessary, and then restores the registers before returning.

Comment: @fuz @RossRidge The code is read from the `.o` generated by `gcc` and injected into another process with `ptrace`. It is supposed to interfere minimally with that process. It would be best if it could be output as a single function by `gcc` so I don't have to deal with linking, etc. It would also be nice if the solution didn't involve compiling a custom `gcc`. I will try to make an `asm` block that saves the registers.

Comment: Can you make an assembly function (in NASM or GNU assembly for example) that preserves (push) the extra registers a _C_ function doesn't, calls the _C_ function and when it returns restore the registers (pop)?

Comment: The 128 byte red zone of the Linux x86-64 ABI means you'll need some sort of glue code anyway to preserve it. The red zone is the 128 bytes under the stack pointer that is guaranteed safe to use without fear that something would asynchronously overwrite (eg. a called function could modify it, but a signal handler couldn't).

Comment: @RossRidge If I just `jmp` to different code `rsp` has not changed so the red zone should still be valid, no?

Comment: No because the code generated by GCC that you're calling can modify the red zone.

Comment: @RossRidge Ok, I just looked up more on this red zone, so I will have to adjust `rsp` as well as `rip`. Then I better pass all the old registers in some memory data structure so I can restore them in an ASM block rather than returning normally from the function.